# Cant compare using If Statement in Java wild error Markers Undefined for Arguments?

Tags: java, if-statement, boolean

Why does it tell me that I can't compare Ints? I am trying to compare this line here and it wont let me all I get is :

```
if (counter1 = 0 || counter2 = 0)
  {
return false;
}
```

Here is the rest of my code for reference.

```
public static boolean checkPassword(String password){
        int length;
        length = password.length();
            if (length < 6 || length > 11){
            System.out.println("Password must be 6 - 10 characters long!"); 
            return false;
            }


        int counter1 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
            if (Character.isLetter(password.charAt(i)))
                counter1++;
        }

        int counter2 = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < password.length(); i++){
            if(Character.isDigit(password.charAt(i)))
                counter2++;
        }

        if (counter1 = 0 || counter2 = 0)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
        }
```

I keep getting Markers Undefined help me :)

Comment: = is not the same as ==.

Comment: @GregS: add that as an answer so it can be upvoted/accepted.

Comment: I just caught it right after I posted it lol. I feel dumb

Comment: @Jonathon: thanks, I let someone else get the votes for this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not using the equality test `==` but the assignment operator `=`.  It is a very common beginners mistake.

```
if (counter1 == 0 || counter2 == 0) {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I messed up wasn't paying attention. Got it now Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

The statement `counter1 = 0` is an assignment, so you're ultimately trying `if (0 || 0)` but the `||` operator expects booleans, not integers.  Use `==` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Because in Java `=` isn't used for comparison.  You need to use `==`  This should be

```
if (counter1 == 0 || counter2 == 0)
{
    return false;
}
```